# How to replace all {!XXX} from string?

Tags: java, salesforce, apex

I have string with multiple {!XXX} phrases. For example:

> Kumar gaurav {!str1} is just {!str2}, adasdas {!str3}

I need to replace all {!str}  values with corresponding str, how to replace all {!str} from my string?

Comment: try replaceAll()  method in java

Comment: Show your effort. This task is easily completed by referring to the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Pattern` and `Matcher`, which provides you the means to query the string for a unknown number of elements, in combination with a regular expression of `\{!str\d\}` which will allow you to break the text down based on the tags

For example...

```
String text = "All that {!str1} is {!str2}";
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>(25);
values.put("{!str1}", "glitters");
values.put("{!str2}", "gold");

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{!str\\d\\}");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String match = matcher.group();         
    text = text.replaceAll("\\" + match, values.get(match));
}

System.out.println(text);
```

Which outputs

```
All that glitters is gold
```

You could also use something like...

```
int previousStart = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (matcher.find()) {
    String match = matcher.group();
    int start = matcher.start();
    int end = matcher.end();

    sb.append(text.substring(previousStart, start));
    sb.append(values.get(match));

    previousStart = end;
}

if (previousStart < text.length()) {
    sb.append(text.substring(previousStart));
}
```

Which does away with the `String` creation in a loop and relies more on the position of the match to cut the original text around the tokens, which makes me happier ;)

Answer (score 0):

use this regex, simple

```
    String string="hello world {!hello}";
    string=string.replaceAll("\\{!(.*?)\\}", "replace");
    System.out.println(string); //this will print (hello world replace)
```